# Opening ChromeBrowser on Android using selenium

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch chrome browser on android app using selenium but I am getting an exception. (The idea is to a browser automatically open and login to a website)
I added a reference to selenium-server-standalone-3.1.2.jar.
Below is the code snippet

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
             WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

             driver.get("http://www.google.com");
             driver.quit();
 }
```

However, I get a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException at `android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)`

If I take out the line  from android manifest I get a unable to find free port error.

Is it not possible to launch a browser on android device this way?

Comment: No.  Use Appium.

Comment: But that would require having a server running on my local machine correct? Basically I want to automate browser actions as part of the actual live app that users can run...

Comment: Appium can be run either as a stand-alone server (desktop) or called as a java service, which is my preferred method.  That should not be an impediment to coding tests for mobile apps, be them native, web, or hybrid, and be the tests with emulators (from Android Studio) or actual connected devices.  I strongly suggest you research Appium and go that route.  Note that when you run as a called service via java code, you can terminate the service when done, or manually through the desktop version.